# Tidy.NET Omit HTML

Tags: tidy

I am trying to get used with Tidy.NET([Project Page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/)), however one simple thing I'm still not able to do.

I'm not able to fix html without Tidy.NET adding following TAGS `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`.
`Setting Options.Xhtml = false`, does not help.

P.S.
Input: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`
Output: `<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>`

I want following result: `<h1>Hello World</h1>`

Comment: Please be clearer; is it that tidy.net adds the tags and you don't want them? what do you enter, what do you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do what you want, but you may consider using Tidy bindings (the "true" one) in .NET, rather than this library that is a complete tidy rewrite, and abandoned since 6 years

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tidy.Options.XmlTags = true;
```